# Cookie gives an error with date

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I followed a tutorial on youtube regarding creating a cookie. I typed in the correct code, but I get an error in the line with:

```
cookie = new Cookie("test_cookie", Long.toString(new Date().getTime()));
```

The error says: `The constructor Date() is undefined.` Does anyone know how I get this error, when he can run it in the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOColvr3pl0

I guess there should be a parameter in it, or?
Best Regards Mads

```
package ExamplePackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/CookieUsageServlet")
public class CookieUsageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Cookie cookie = getCookie(request, response);
        printResponse(response, cookie);
    }

    private Cookie getCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Cookie cookie = null;
        Cookie[] cookiesArray = request.getCookies();
        if(cookiesArray != null) {
            for(int x = 0; x < cookiesArray.length; x++) {
                if(cookiesArray[x].getName().equals("test_cookie")) cookie = cookiesArray[x];
            }
        }
        if(cookie != null) {
            System.out.println("cookie retrieved");
        } else {
            int timeToExpireCookie = new Integer(getServletContext().getInitParameter("time-to-expire-cookie")).intValue();
            cookie = new Cookie("test_cookie", Long.toString(new Date().getTime()));
            cookie.setMaxAge(timeToExpireCookie);
            cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath()); // Sti til login
            System.out.println("Cookie created...");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
        return cookie;
    }
    private void printResponse(HttpServletResponse response, Cookie cookie) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        printWriter.println("<html>");
        printWriter.println("<head><title>Cookie In JAVA servlet</title></head>");
        printWriter.println("<body>");
        printWriter.println("<cookie name: " + cookie.getName() + "<br>");
        printWriter.println("<cookie value: " + cookie.getValue() + "<br>");
        printWriter.println("<time to expire cookie in seconds: " + cookie.getMaxAge() + "<br>");
        printWriter.println("</body>");
        printWriter.println("</html>");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.sql.Date` does not have no-arg constuctor.

`java.sql.Date` change it to `java.util.Date`

```
cookie = new Cookie("test_cookie", Long.toString(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
```

Comment: Ah of course good point. Thanks a lot :-) When I run the program I get the error:

HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

type Status report

message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

Do you know how this can be?

Best Regards
Mads

Comment: override `doGet` method as well

Comment: Something like this?: @Override protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { processRequest(request, response); }

Comment: asmall mistake, make it public to access

Answer (score 2):

You're importing [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) - which *doesn't* have a parameterless constructor. You meant [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), which does.

However, there's no need to create a `Date` object at all in order to get the current time in milliseconds-since-the-Unix-epoch:

```
cookie = new Cookie("test_cookie", Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

(Or ideally, inject some kind of `Clock` representation into your code, so you can test it more easily.)

Comment: Ah of course good point. Thanks a lot :-) When I run the program I get the error:

HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

type Status report

message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

Do you know how this can be?

Best Regards
Mads

Comment: @user1883095: Well the error describes itself - your servlet doesn't support `GET` because you've only overridden `doPost`. Override `doGet` as well (or instead).

Comment: Something like this?:

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

Comment: @user1883095: Yup, so long as you don't need a body for the request. Anyway, by this point we're a fair way from the original problem in the question. I suggest you try to continue yourself, and post a new question if you still have problems.

Comment: @user1883095 if this answer helped you with your problem, please consider accepting it (with the green tick to the left of it) as a reference for future visitors :)